# Why result of [[1]] is equal to '1' in Lua language?

Tags: lua, lua-table

`[[1]]`[image: result in my terminal on macOS 10.15.7 with Lua 5.4.3]

WithLua 5.4.3, On expression [[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLLzI.png)]], And result is '1',type is string. I can not understand, and not find any useful info on Lua document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1

It's introduced in section 3.1.

> Literal strings can also be defined using a long format enclosed by long brackets. We define an opening long bracket of level n as an opening square bracket followed by n equal signs followed by another opening square bracket. So, an opening long bracket of level 0 is written as [[, an opening long bracket of level 1 is written as [=[, and so on.

The long format is usually used to write multiline literal strings and multiline comments.

```
print([===[
"Hello
world!"]===])

--[=[
"Hello
world!"
]=]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usefull if you need for example control sequences like the \n not interpreted by Lua.

Simple example...

```
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> [[one]]
one
> "one"
one
> -- With \n
> [[one\n]]
one\n
> "one\n"
one

>
```